# PDFTron color conversion

Tags: c#, colors, pdftron

I have managed to convert color from hex string `#FF2A1A` to `ColorPt` using such code:

```
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strColor);
return new ColorPt(color.R / 255.0, color.G / 255.0, color.B / 255.0);
```

Am I right? And now I need to scan pdf, and convert color of existing pdf elements (annotations, for example) from PDFTron `ColorPt` to hex string to display in browser. How can I do it?

Comment: Why divide by 255? 1A/255 is 26/255 not the 26 you wanted.

Comment: @BugFinder the API for ColorPT takes in floats ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. The actual meaning of the values depends on the ColorSpace. So in DeviceGray PDF color space, only the first value (channel) of ColorPT is read, and 0.0 meaning black, and 1.0 meaning black. This is why the System.Drawing values need to be converted to a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: It would really help to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Why is converting hex color to ColorPt, and then back to hex color again?

Comment: Oh, in fact I need to convert ColorPt to hex string. Convertion from hex string to ColorPt is for my personal interest

Comment: I am curious why converting to Hex string is important? Also, are you creating all the page content? Or are you editing an existing page? Note, PDFNet offers PDF to HTML/EPUB, and PDF to SVG conversions out of the box.